# JobLibValueError When Using GridSearchCV from SKLearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SciKit-Learn's grid search to find the best parameters for my Random Forest.  I'm doing this as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=50))])
parameters = {
'clf__n_estimators': (50, 100, 200),
'clf__max_depth': (50, 150, 250),
'clf__min_samples_split': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
'clf__min_samples_leaf': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1,verbose=1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search.fit(X, Y)
print 'Best score: %0.3f' % grid_search.best_score_
print 'Best parameters set:'

best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
    print '\t%s: %r' % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name])

predictions = grid_search.predict(X)
print classification_report(Y, predictions)
```

Unfortunately, I get a `JobLibValueError` that points to:

```
---> 14 grid_search.fit(X, Y)
```

For reference, my X looks like this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 76613   76614   76615   76616   76617   76618   76619   76620   _engaged_time   _title
0   0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 20000.0 54
1   0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 55000.0 40
```

and my Y values are just a bunch of engagement times (integers).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of error?

Comment: Why would you want to add a single operation to `Pipeline`?

Comment: I posted a possible solution. Can you upload the X and y to try to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try

1) to replace:

`from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV`

**with**

`from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV`

2) to update sklearn module

`pip install -U scikit-learn` or `conda install scikit-learn`

Solution 1) solved a similar problem that I had.